# how to make put bold arrows between text

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I am putting arrows next to text. I want to change their color and make them bold.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\uparrow$ areal density
        \item $\uparrow$ data rates
    \end{itemize} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

is it possible to do this without adding \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{itemize}
\item[\MVRightarrow] some thing 
\item[\color{blue!50!green}\rotatebox{90}{\MVRightarrow}] areal density
\item[\color{red!70!cyan}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\MVRightarrow}}] data rates  
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need upward arrow.

Comment: @NAASI  `\rotatebox{90}{\MVRightarrow}`

Comment: Thankyou. Didn't know about \rotatebox{.} before